# htaccess problem in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

There are two kind of pages -

1. www.mysite.com/about.php
2. www.mysite.com/winners.php?y=2008

I want to make them like - 
 1. www.mysite.com/about
 2. www.mysite.com/winners/2008

my htaccess is like -

```
RewriteEngine On
#removing .php ext(type-1)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#for type-2 (with parameter)
RewriteRule winners/([0-9]+)/?$ winners.php?y=$1 [L]
RewriteRule winning-photograph/([0-9]+)/?$ winning-photograph.php?y=$1 [L]
RewriteRule award-giving/([0-9]+)/?$ award-giving.php?y=$1 [L]
RewriteRule album-launch/([0-9]+)/?$ album-launch.php?y=$1 [L]
RewriteRule district-fest/([0-9]+)/?$ district-fest.php?y=$1 [L]
RewriteRule lifetime-achievement-awards/([0-9]+)/?$ lifetime-achievement-awards.php?y=$1 [L]
RewriteRule critics-award-for-tv/([0-9]+)/?$ critics-award-for-tv.php?y=$1 [L]
RewriteRule photography-book/([0-9]+)/?$ photography-book.php?y=$1 [L]
```

The two section of this htaccess are not working at the same time. what can I do? also - is there a way to simplify the 2nd section?

Comment: Do you want to hide or encode the url?

Comment: @Ankit do you mean clean URLs? @Emrul Hasan you can try to replace `[L]` with `[L,QSA]`

Comment: In what way are they not working?

Comment: Instead of clean url you can encode url feature.

Comment: tell some more about clean url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first RewriteRule is basically preventing all the other rules from executing.  It does that rule for both types of your URLs, then the [L] flag stops it from evaluating the other rules.

I would say put that rule at the very end.  Do all the more-specific ones first, then have that as a generic one for all other cases, only to be evaluated if the rest of the rules didn't match the current URL.